# Are the various OpenCL boiler plate types safe to copy?

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm a bit confused as to the underlying type of the various types like "cl_mem" or "cl_context". By the opencl header, it seems as if they are actually struct instance pointers which would make them safe to copy but as far as I can tell they don't have any members accessible by either . or -> operators.

Essentially, are they safe to copy when passing them into function arguments or pushing them into a vector, etc?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, they are pointers internally. As such, they can be freely passed as function arguments or kept in a vector.

You shouldn't be using them to access any members directly because the implementation is free to change at any time.

I'll direct you to the `cl.hpp` and `cl2.hpp` headers that wrap the C functionality nicely for C++ use.

Comment: While they may be pointers internally, you can think of them as "handles", and yes, you can copy them around. Can can Retain and Release if you want, or keep track of things yourself so you don't leak resources or use a handle again after deleting the object.